# I got access to the 'trusted user' tools privilege before attaining 20000 reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges

My reputation is now at 19997, but I already got awarded access to the trusted user tools. Seems like a bug to me?

[image]

I never crossed the 20k line:

[image: Screenshot of reputation history shows 35 rep gained yesterday and no net reputation changes today.]

Comment: Presumably you gained enough reputation from something like an upvote to hit 20k, and then that reputation was lost by it being retracted or something, the notice isn't retroactively removed. I would be surprised if you actually do still have access to the tools

Comment: I edited my question with my last reputation chagnes, this is not the case...

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't prove anything, the vote and retraction wouldn't appear in your history if in a short timeframe (the same day iirc)

Comment: You briefly reached 20k then dropped down again. Happens if someone voted and retracted their vote

Comment: @NickA ok I see. Never mind then :)

Comment: *Something* happened today; otherwise it wouldn't bother telling you that there were no net reputation changes.

Comment: Ok should I close/delete my question?